# Javascript scroll issue in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table that consists of left and right part.
Essentially something like this:

```
<div id="wholeTable">
    <div id="leftPart"></div>
    <div id="rightPart"></div>
</div>
```

I need to have vertical scroll on complete table and horizontal on right part, but the event will only be triggered on right part of the table.

The problem is in Firefox and internet explorer, there is a lag in scroll of the left part.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$('#rightPart').on('scroll', function (event) {
    var leftPart = $('#leftPart').get()[0];
    var top = -1 * event.currentTarget.scrollTop + 'px';
    leftPart.style.top = top;
});
```

P.S. turning off smooth scroll in Internet Explorer solves the problem there,
but it is not accepted as solution and Firefox is also not solved with that.
Also scroll on whole table is not accepted, because right part need to be 
horizontal scrollable.

Comment: Please provide a complete demo or jsfiddle including CSS!

Comment: A superficial example: https://jsfiddle.net/netcov5h/1/

Comment: Included jQuery -> https://jsfiddle.net/netcov5h/2/